# How to do 64-bit by 32-bit division?

Tags: arm

I use IAR with STM32 and I need 64-bit arithmetic. How to implement 32-bit array for 64-bit arithmetic?

For example I have a 64 bit value `0x3B5456DF32` stored in a 32-bit array

```
A[0]= 0x3B
A[1] = 0x5456DF32
```

I have to divide it by `B = 0x3216523`

Answer (score 2):

There are so many questions like this before. Please do a search and look for the most appropriate answer for you before asking

- [64 bit by 32 bit division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3472117/995714)
- [Signed 64 by 32 integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089265/995714)
- [64 bit division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366286/995714)
- [64/32-bit division on a processor with 32/16-bit division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772398/995714)
- [64bit/32bit division faster algorithm for ARM / NEON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15215196/995714)
- [How does one do integer (signed or unsigned) division on ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8348030/995714)