# 64bit/32bit division faster algorithm for ARM / NEON?

Tags: c, arm

I am working on a code in which at two places there are  64bit by 32 bit fixed point division and the result is  taken in 32 bits. These two places are together taking more than 20% of my total time taken. So I feel like if I could remove the 64 bit division, I could optimize the code well. In NEON we can have some 64 bit instructions. Can any one suggest some routine to get the bottleneck resolved by using some faster implementation.

Or if I could make the 64 bit/32 bit division in terms of 32bit/32 bit division in C, that also is fine?

If any one has some idea, could you please help me out?

Comment: why the vote to close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a lot of fixed-point arithmetic in the past and did a lot of research looking for fast 64/32 bit divisions myself. If you google for 'ARM division' you will find *tons* of great links and discussion about this issue.

The best solution for ARM architecture, where even a 32 bit division may not be available in hardware is here:

http://www.peter-teichmann.de/adiv2e.html

This assembly code is *very* old, and your assembler may not understand the syntax of it. It is however worth porting the code to your toolchain. It is the fastest division code for your special case I've seen so far, and trust me: I've benchmarked them all :-)

Last time I did that (about 5 years ago, for CortexA8) this code was about 10 times faster than what the compiler generated.

This code doesn't use NEON. A NEON port would be interesting. Not sure if it will improve the performance much though.

**Edit:**

I found the code with assembler ported to GAS (GNU Toolchain). This code is working and tested:

**Divide.S**

```
.section ".text"

.global udiv64

udiv64:
    adds      r0,r0,r0
    adc       r1,r1,r1

    .rept 31
        cmp     r1,r2   
        subcs   r1,r1,r2  
        adcs    r0,r0,r0
        adc     r1,r1,r1
    .endr

    cmp     r1,r2
    subcs   r1,r1,r2
    adcs    r0,r0,r0

    bx      lr
```

**C-Code:**

```
extern "C" uint32_t udiv64 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c);

int32_t fixdiv24 (int32_t a, int32_t b)
/* calculate (a<<24)/b with 64 bit immediate result */
{
  int q;
  int sign = (a^b) < 0; /* different signs */
  uint32_t l,h;
  a = a<0 ? -a:a;
  b = b<0 ? -b:b;
  l = (a << 24);
  h = (a >> 8);
  q = udiv64 (l,h,b);
  if (sign) q = -q;
  return q;
}
```

Comment: The syntax is really odd, but if I'm not mistaken, the algorithm you linked is just conditionally subtracting each power-of-two multiple of the divisor that fits (using condition codes rather than branches) and keeping a tally. Is this correct? If so, you might could write the exact same thing in C and get the same performance if the compiler is decent.

Comment: Well, *if* the compiler is decent you should get the same result. In my experience ARM compilers do a great job as long as everything you do is 32 bit arithmetic. As soon as you use 64 bit integers (required here, because you can't express the carry flag in C) they switch into dumb mode and generate not-so-great code.

Comment: This code fails when `a` is -2147483648. In this case, the `-a` in `a  a<0 ? -a:a;` overflows. In common implementations, the result is -2147483648, and then the result of `a >> 8` is implementation defined and typically results in the wrong quotient being calculated later.

Comment: Compilers won't do multi-word instructions with the `carry`.  This doesn't map to `C`.  If you have `long long` types, it might be possible, but I suspect the `assembler` ignores some boundary cases that the compiler won't.  See: **Very important: FDIV64 only works properly with unsigned integers, and the quotient must fit into 32 bit!**

Comment: The link seems broken.

Comment: [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110213102004/http://www.peter-teichmann.de/adiv2e.html) is a working archive link to the original website.